# Can I see my Play Store wishlist on the web?

Tags: google-play-store

Google Play store recently gained a long-awaited wishlist feature in the 3.9.16 version of the application. I was wondering whether the wishlist could be modified from the web version of the Play Store while using e.g. a PC. I looked for around the website but wasn't able to find a way to do it, but perhaps I'm missing something.

Also, would the wishlist sync to all Android devices connected to the same Google account, or is it just local to the device it has been set up on?

Answer (score 13):

EDIT: Yes - As Al points out in the comments, the url is https://play.google.com/wishlist

Old Answer:

Basically no.

The same question [was asked on Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/11s2x7/play_store_wishlist_on_computer/).  It's not a stretch of the imagination to assume that they will roll out a web version, but as yet there's been no official word from Google.

Answer (score 2):

> I was wondering whether the wishlist could be modified from the web
>   version of the Play Store while using e.g. a PC.

So far it is not possible, we must wait for the new web version of the Play Store.

> Also, would the wishlist sync to all Android devices connected to the
>   same Google account, or is it just local to the device it has been set
>   up on?

Yes, Wish list is hold in Google cloud and it is synced among all your devices connected to the same Google account.

I am very happy with this feature and I use it extensively. I can even automatically monitor any future updates of apps on my wish list with a help of a new feature "Observed apps" in [Changelog Droid application (CD)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cypressworks.changelogviewer). How to do it:

CD cannot synchronize with your wishlist because Google Play Store does not have an API so third party apps cannot interact with it. However, you can populate Observed apps in CD manually from within the CD itself or by opening Google Play on your device and sharing wishlist items one by one to CD. It seems to be tedious if you have your wishlist very long, but you will rewarded. Here is real example how Observed apps in Changelog Droid helped me:

In my country we have independent consumer organization dTest. They published in Google Play its own app dTest some time ago. But it worked only on phones, not on tablets. Because I don't want to have this app on my phone, but on my tablet, I put this app in my Wish list and shared it to Changelog Droid's Observed apps. After some time Changelog Droid informed me about new dTest version with tablet support so I was able to install it on my Nexus 7 the first day when this new version for tablets appeared in Google Play :)

Answer (score 2):

To access your wishlist from the browser signed in to Google Play you have to click on the "Settings" button (upper right corner, gear icon) and choose "My Orders" option from the drop down list. Next on the left hand side under "Apps", "Movies", "Music", etc. you will find "My Wishlist" option. Click on that option to see/modify your wishlist.

Answer (score 0):

When signed you'll find "My wishlist" in the menu on the left. (Or just go to it directly at [play.google.com/wishlist](https://play.google.com/wishlist).)