# How can I share my Google Play wish list with other people?

Tags: google-play-store, google-play-wishlist

I've got a birthday coming up, and people ask me what I'd like to get. Among other things, I have a few items in my Google Play wish list, and I know that I can see it at https://play.google.com/wishlist (thank you [Martyn](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/32201/can-i-see-my-play-store-wishlist-on-the-web)). But that's a plain URL without user information. I can't share that to others.

I am looking for an URL or feature that lets my friends see what I've put my wish list.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Changelog Droid app which featured one touch functionality to import your complete wish list into so called observed apps category and then you can export your observed apps to SD card (Preferences, Export/Import, Export/Import observed apps) and sent this file (/sdcard/cd_observed.json) to your friends which can import your observed list into their Changelog Droid. Yes they should install this app too, but this app is so good that they will be glad to use it anyway :)

For a few items in a wish list it is an overkill, but I have over one hundred apps in my wish list so in such a situation Changelog Droid is the acceptable way to realize sharing my complete wish list.

Comment: This requires others to have an Android device, and that they are able and willing to get that app and import file. It also only provides a snapshot, not a live view of my wish list.

Comment: I know all these shortcomings, but I shared it, because it can be useful for someone :)
You can just mail the /sdcard/cd_observed.json file, it is the text file. But if you have only a few items on your wish list you can mail to your friends all app links anyway :)