# How do I Export/Extract my Play-Store Wishlist?

Tags: google-play-store, google-play-wishlist

It's gotten too big/unwieldy to manage on the Play Store, I want to store it elsewhere & manage it there.
And I **sooo** don't want to manually open each item and grab its link (& maybe some other useful data)!

Some kind of scraping tool, user script, or addon used on the website, might do the trick?
Instead of bothering with the actual android app...

Thank-you.

Comment: [APP solution](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/64377/131553) seems to be the only way, since a) [Google takeout](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/204765/131553) doesn't seem to have this data b) Google Play help doesn't talk of this c) My quick search shows there hasn't been a ticket raised before with Google d) You could ask the Google community or contact Google help (if you are a born optimist)! // This isn't posted as an answer since you are specific about not using apps// +1

Comment: Unlike Amazon wish list that can be public, allowing users to buy you gifts, that can't be done with Play Store wishlists. That's probably why you can't share them